# Database modeling (best design possible for performance of this specific case)

Tags: mysql, database

I'm currently developing a Minecraft Plugin in which will use database for some data, that data is splitted in time-lines, basically the table would have BIGINT fields, such as:
kills, deaths, winstreak, losstreak, things like that, but they are splitted between player kits, which means the player has some setups of tools he can use, and each setup needs its own row because of the need to differentiate the deaths of setup1 with the deaths of setup2, and at the same time use the ORDER BY of mysql to generate its leaderboards.

The table will be indexed of course, since we are doing top leaderboards of users, and that table will just grow exponentially more and more, we are looking forward to design it the best way (in performance).

The setups are predefined, the player can only customize but their name never changes, so I thought about using the name as a field in the columns of the table.

The time lines are: daily, weekly, monthly, and lifetime.

I am looking for the most performant way of this, since these ORDER BY can be called a lot of times in a second.

I've thought about creating 4 tables for each setup, setupkey_daily, setupkey_weekly ... setupkey_lifetime.

The other way would be to instead of having a table for each timeline, having it specified in the column, like: setupkey_daily in a column, and many rows related to the same player UUID.

I'm thinking about the amount of iterations this table of only for each timeline would have to do, against the tables specifically for each setup.

Any ideas of what should I do, if there's a right design, the most performant one, tips to increase the performance of these queries if necessary?

Comment: How many rows (estimated) will be in each table?  Try to write one of the necessary queries that will use the largest table.  It will be easier to discuss your questions with that mockup in front of us.

Comment: @RickJames if I have to say, I would expect at least 300k users (to be safe), we're currently with another project launched in the company and that table has 100k users in 4 months.

Comment: If any common query needs to scan all 300K rows, performance will be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the database for storage only, and write a caching layer over it that manages the ordered lists in memory. It can read from the database when it starts up, write changes to the database after applying them in memory, and manage the ordering in memory.

When you need to present a leaderboard, it comes from memory immediately and is very fast.

Comment: What if there is a separate backend service that updates the database? How would you invalidate the entire cache?

Comment: @OneCricketeer You'll need to work out the requirements of those updates. If they're very frequent and fast consistency is required, then they'll have to go through the caching layer. Or, if slower consistency is OK, the database can poll for cheaper updates. Other solutions are possible depending on the specific requirements.